# Brakes smoking and rpm off chrylser 300

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, chrysler, chrysler-300

So my buddy bottomed out his car kinda back and it was revving high but not speeding up so he took it to his mechanic and had him check the transmission but he said it was all good so he took it home and then noticed his front left tire was smoking and saw his rotor was glowing bright orange so we replaced the rotor and pad and caliper because the caliper was stuck and the breaking was good and it ran better for a bit but there was a little noise and we determined the bearing in that tire was also bad so we replaced that to and now a day later it is doing the same exact thing as before, any ideas what it could possibly be?

Comment: Possible problem with a hose? If you have all 4 wheels off the ground Is any other wheel locking up? Excluding rf, rr specifically? Or are you talking about the lack of power? Please be more specific. What engine do you have and is this awd?

Comment: It's a 2009 chrysler 300 , 2.7 and no its rwd  and when giving gas the rpms are going up but speed doesn't follow well and it's acting like it doesn't wanna shift up

Comment: Can you confirm it’s not the brakes locking up again?

Comment: "when giving gas the rpms are going up but speed doesn't follow well and it's acting like it doesn't wanna shift up", well what else would you expect when driving around with one or more of the wheel brakes engaged? What John Lord stated below about a pinched brake line could very well be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

is it pulling in that direction?  The only thing I can think of is maybe when he bottomed it out, he pinched a brake line.